# Can't use drivers for NVIDIA for my notebook

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Six month ago all be fine...I have a NVidia GeForce MX150 video card in my notebook running Ubuntu 18.04,in "Additional drivers" i choose 415 version, my settings in grub GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia-drm.modeset=1", but system starting with Intel drivers, terminal show prime-select query - nvidia, but my system used Intel...pls, help someone

Comment: You have to remove "nvidia-drm.modeset=1" from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT then run `update-grub`.

Comment: I did that, and i have just purple screen..